# Ubuntu 16.04.2 and 16.10 screen goes black randomly for a second

Tags: 16.04, graphics, intel-graphics, flicker

This problem has occurred on 16.10 which is why I decided to stick with 16.04. Now with the 16.04.2 update, I'm getting the same issue.

Once in a while, very randomly (most noticeable while in the Terminal using the up key to get to a previous command or using the backspace key) my whole screen flickers black.

Before with Ubuntu 16.04.1, I didn't have that problem. I would update to Kernel 4.6 and install the Intel Graphics Update Tool and everything worked perfectly. Doing the same (without the Kernel update) on 16.04.2 does the same thing as other distros with Kernel 4.8 (or Ubuntu Gnome at 4.6).

Given I don't get the issue on the LiveDVD I tried not installing any drivers but that didn't help.

I've also tried adding i915.enable_psr=0 and i915.enable_rc6=0 to GRUB to no avail.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The X server in 16.04.2 point release has been back-ported from 16.10. That must be why you're facing the same issue on both of them.

I had been experiencing a lot of random flickering as well, after the upgrade.

Removing the new X stack seems to have fixed it:

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04
```

However, `ubuntu-desktop` will also be removed!

So, you need to do the following straight away:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core

sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-input-all libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx
```

[Source](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/02/install-remove-enablement-stacks-ubuntu-16-04/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I've been searching since 16.04.2 came out! I'll try that and tell you how it went. Thanks :)

Comment: If it works though it doens't really solve anything in the long run. If the next stacks are incremental, they'll all start from the buggy one won't they?

Comment: A lot of people seem to be experiencing this issue. Check these ([1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1634451) & [2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1634449)) bug reports for instance. So it most probably will be fixed soon. You may try to re-enable the X stack in the next 16.04 point release or if 16.04.2 receives any further updates to the X server and see how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't know so many people were having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem running Ubuntu 16.04 with Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

My monitor was blanking randomly and unpredictably for a few seconds, mainly after coming back from the suspend state.

My solution was to make changes in the system settings. 
Open the settings program and click on **Devices**, then select **Displays**. I lowered the refresh rate from 60 to 50Hz and the problem has disappeared.